# Multiplication Property of Vector Inequality

Tags: matrix-equations

I'm a beginner of matrix inequality. Now I have a vector inequality like below

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A \lambda \succeq \mu 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $A$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $\lambda \succeq 0$ is a $n \times 1$ vector. May I ask if I can draw the following conclusion?

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 \lambda \succeq A^{-1} \mu 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If the equation above is correct, how can I prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your matrix is semidefinite, its inverse might not be defined.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But let me assume this inverse matrix exists. How about that?

Comment: Then the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: @joriki Thanks. My question is if we assume A is invertible, then can we derive the second inequality?

Comment: I know. I'm just saying that you should correct the question to state that the matrix is positive definite if that's the case you're interested in.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  I have edited the problem description to let $A$ is symmetric positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. Choose $\lambda=0$; certainly $0\succeq\mu$ does not imply $0\succeq A^{-1}\mu$, for instance for $\mu=\pmatrix{-1\\0}$ and $A^{-1}=\pmatrix{3&-1\\-1&3}$.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample. It's very helpful.